# How can I ask the user for a word , and the program stops running when the user writes stop and the program shows all the words aside stop

Tags: javascript

The question says, Write a program that asks the user for a word until the user types "stop". The program then shows each of these words, except "stop"...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/17898569

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it you want?

```js
var d = [];
while(1){
var word = prompt("Enter some word?");
if( word == 'stop') break;
d.push(word);
}

console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thanks so much ..it worked....I was creating only an outer variable with the prompt...so it wasn't working....thanks